# Unable to burn program into NodeMCU when it's soldered to a board

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I seem to have come across a strange issue. When my NodeMCU is connected onto a PCB circuit, I am unable to burn the program into it (even though the board is not powered up!). It says:

> espcomm_open failed
>
> espcomm_upload_mem failed

But the very same NodeMCU, when I pull it out of the circuit and try to upload the code works fine. Why is this?

P.S. Well, I can pull out the NodeMCU, burn the program and re-insert it, but I am trying to understand what's happening behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your comm port is getting closed or used when you plug it into the pcb circuit. So the Arduino IDE cannot comunicate with the nodeMCU com port.

I had simmilar problems and after xxx attempts i uploaded it when the Nodemcu was unpluged from the PCB and worked perfectly.

I lately found out that the pcb used com port pin.

Comment: True Johnny, in the PCB the analog output that was supposed to go the ADC was connected to the RX pin of the Nodemcu. Lost precious time to this stupid mistake.

Comment: i know how you feel :) at least you found the answer to your problem :)